# How to fix my admin login code

Tags: php, authentication

I was wondering if anyone knows what is wrong with my php code and how I can fix it. Everytime I try to see if it works it just tells me "The information is incorrect, Click here to try again" but the problem is I haven't written in the username or password. It directly tells me that the information is wrong and try again. Can anybody help me and tell me what is wrong with my code and what

```
    <?php
    session_start();
     if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
        header("location: index.php"); 
         exit();
     }
    ?>
    <?php 
    // Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
    if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

        $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
            $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
           // Connect to the MySQL database  
           include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
            // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
           if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >0); // count the row nums
               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
                  $id = $row["id"];
             }
     $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
     $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
     $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
     header("location: index.php");
     exit();
} else {
    echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set your if and else condition in the right place.

Try this.

```
<?php
session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: index.php"); 
     exit();
 }

// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
        $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
       // Connect to the MySQL database  
       include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
        // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
       if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >0); // count the row nums
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
             $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
             $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
             header("location: index.php");
             exit();
           }
        }else{
            echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
            exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's this line of code that is failing:

```
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
```

You need to write the HTML code that posts the username and password

Also, you probably meant to put your "else" condition after the SQL query, like this:

```
 <?php
session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: index.php"); 
     exit();
 }
?>
<?php 
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
   // Connect to the MySQL database  
   include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
   if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >0){ // count the row nums
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $id = $row["id"];
         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         header("location: index.php");
         }
        exit();
     }else{
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    }   
} 
exit();
?>
```

So that if no results are returned from the query.. then you get the error message

Why are you using preg_replace to replace everything but numbers and letters on the userName and password fields?  That prevents using many valid character such as !, ^, etc.  It would be better for security if the user can use these characters in their passwords.

If it is malicious user input you are concerned about, you can runn all user input through a function, such as this:

```
function clean_input($var){// clean all user input
$var = strip_tags(stripslashes(trim(rtrim($var))));
$var = htmlspecialchars($var);
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
return $var;
}
```

...and then run all user input data through the function like so:

```
$errors = array();
if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {//handle the user name input
    $user_name = clean_input($_POST['user_name']);
} else {//user_name not entered
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a user name';
}
if (!empty($_POST['password'])) {//handle the password input
    $user_id = '';
    $password = clean_input($_POST['password']);
    $q = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
        $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
        $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
    }
} else {//password not entered
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter a password';
}
if(!empty($errors)){
echo '<h3 class="error">Error!</h3>
    <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br/>';
    foreach($errors as $msg){
        echo " - $msg<br/>\n";
    }
echo '</p><p class="error">Please try again.</p>';  
}else{
            header("location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: @user3200510 Could you please accept it as as answer, if my suggestions worked and were helpful... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I suppose your code is called "login.php". So instead of this else code

```
else {
    echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
    exit();
}
```

You actually want to return the html form here.

```
else {
    echo '<form class="login-form"> .........';
    exit();
}
```